# A change to mysql configuration and my.cnf file is not visible even after mysql restarts

Tags: mysql

Background: MySQL running in Kubernetes

After changing MySQL's `wait_timeout` from 28800 to 29800 by using `SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 29800;` To my surprise, I can not observe this change by using `show variables like 'wait_timeout'`. I can only observe this change by using `show GLOBAL variables`.

```
mysql> show global variables like 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> set global wait_timeout=29800;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show global variables like 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 29800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout  | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I looked up MySQL Documentation and understand that `show variables` is equal to `show session variables`. So I decided to restart the server by killing the MySQL container since I think this will refresh the cache and enable a new user session to observe the change.

The pod was re-built by Kubernetes Controller after the `docker kill` command(`my.cnf` file is persisted), the server was restarted.
But the same thing happens, confusingly, `29800` still can only be viewed with `show global variables`.

What went wrong? Does a variable modification done by `set GLOBAL variables` declaration can only be observed with `show global variables` ? Which doesn't seem to make much sense.

And how come a modification by current session cannot be observed by `show session variables like '***'`?

Comment: Do `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';` to see if it really did restart.

Answer (score 0):

`wait_timeoout` is rather cryptic.  There are about 4 values in 2 dimensions:

- `GLOBAL` vs `SESSION`: you probably dealt with that by restarting.  The `GLOBAL` value is used to initialize the `SESSION` value when opening a connection.  That is, `SET GLOBAL ...` has no impact on most `SESSION` variables of currently running connections.
- batch versus interactive.  `interactive_timeout` is used when using the mysql commandline tool.  `wait_timeout` is for apps (PHP, Java, etc).

Traditionally, `SET GLOBAL` sticks only until the next restart.  However, with MySQL 8.0, there is a `PERSIST` option to make it stick.

To see the timeouts:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';
SHOW SESSIOn VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';
```

If you are disconnected and reconnected due to `wait_timeout`, the `STATUS` value `Aborted_clients` will be incremented by 1.